# There is a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when I use `mvn hpi:run`

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to create a Jenkins plugin then I use maven to debug my plugin,I download the PlotPlugin to study how to write the code.But when I type `mvn hpi:run` under the directory of the [PlotPlugun](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Plot+Plugin),something is wrong after jenkins runs on my computer.There is an error like this:

[image: error]

In this case ,I can use jenkins on localhost:8080 but I can't create a new item,when I create a new item there is something wrong:

[image]

My system environment is something like this :

[image]

Can someone help me?I don't know what happened.TAT

Comment: That is something in your code. You'll need to post some code, alternatively start removing code until it starts working. There may be more on the stacktrace in your jenkins log

Answer (score 0):

I fond the reason, the version of the jenkins is not suitable with this plugin,so I changed the version of the jenkins in parent tag.Then it worked for me.

I think there is a bug with xStream in the jenkins ver. 1.532.1.Because I use `java -jar jenkins.war` to run the war package of the jenkins ver. 1.532.1 there is the same error as I met.After I changed the version to the 1.500 or other version the error disappeared .